# How to UnHook properly?

Tags: c#, hook, unhookwindowshookex

I made a very simple Hook codes (I'm a beginner).

I opened Notepad and tested.

If I press ANY key it make a beep and printed itself.

Except "x" key, it is a terminator key.

**Question** :

I do not want to see "x" key printed. I just quit the program. What do I have to do ?

```
namespace HookingStudy
{
    class HookingClass          
    {
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = hookCallBack;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;                    
        public static void Main()
        {
            Beep(1111, 222);
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
            Application.Run();
        }
        private static IntPtr hookCallBack(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if( nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr) WM_KEYDOWN )
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                if( vkCode.ToString() == "88" )                 //   88 ("x" key)
                {
                    Beep(7777, 222);
                    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);     
                    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); 
                }
                Beep(2222, 55);
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);  
        }
        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using( Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess() )
            using( ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule )
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(13, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }                   
        }
        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL")]                             
        extern public static void Beep(int freq, int dur);      
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
    }  
}
```

Comment: `vkCode.ToString() == "88"` is funny.

Comment: Yes. Fortunately, it works though.

Comment: Then tell please what doesn't work? Does `UnhookWindowHookEx` gets called? You are not checking for return values.

Comment: What does `UnhookWindowsHookEx` return? If it is non-zero then what dose `GetLastError` return?

Comment: @Sinatr Simply, I do not want to see the terminator "x" printed at Notepad.

Comment: @Richard Hmm. Let me check it out.

Comment: @Richard It says "true"

Comment: @Richard When I press "x" key.

Comment: @Richard Sorry, I do not know what "GetLastError" is. I'm a beginner.

Comment: All supported Win32 APIs are documented on MSDN, including  [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @Richard Thanks I'll check it out. Now I do not have any "Error" messages. So, it will be some time later.

Comment: You have to return (IntPtr)1 from your hook callback to get the keystroke swallowed.  That's kinda hard to do when you terminate the program.  You can use SynchronizationContext.Current.Post() to get code to execute later, after the hook callback returns.

Comment: @HansPassant Wooo. That sounds Super-difficult to implement. OK, Thank. I'll try it out with leisure. Thanks Again for your Confirmation. That is really precious.

Comment: Nah... That's far beyond my small brain. Thanks any ways.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to see the terminator `x` printed at Notepad

Then do not call next hook in chain:

```
return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
```

The idea of hooking it to install own handler *prior* existing handlers (afair from winapi). By intercepting (like you are doing it already) you are not only *listening*, but still invoking previous handlers with that call.

Try something like (untested):

```
if( vkCode == 88)
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out.

Comment: Hmmm.. I added "return (IntPtr) 1;". It looks like not bad. But, The program itself is still running (behind). How can I quit it permanently ? Thanks.

Comment: *"program itself is still running"* - that's another problem. `Application.Run()` is this WPF?

Comment: No. Just plain Console ones.

Comment: I've clicked it. Thanks. So... can You please tell me the exact point that I put a "terminator line" in my codes ?

Comment: Put it instead of line where you try to kill current process.

Comment: Hmmm. That is the Question itself. I think I have to put it "return;" point. But, I have "return;" already there. If I change "return;" to "permanent quit code", it just make "x" typed.